# cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'

Tags: c#, action

Passing a method with a parameter to a method that accepts an Action type parameter results in the syntax error

> Cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'

However if I pass it a method that does not have any parameters it works fine.

I assume `C#` is doing something automatically when I pass it a method without a parameter.

I would like to know what it is doing behind the scenes and how to do the same with method that has parameters.

```
public void Invoke(Action action){ /*Code Here */ }

public void Method1(){ /*Code Here */}

public void Method2(int param){ /*Code Here */ }

public void test()
{
    int testParam = 1;
    //** This works
    Invoke(Method1);
    //** This does not work
    Invoke(Method2(testParam));     
}
```

Comment: `Invoke(() => Method2(testParam));`

Comment: `Method2(testParam)` you just called a function.  It doesn't return anything, so you get an error.

Comment: @Servy, this is not a duplicate question because I received a different error message.

Comment: @TheColonel26  You have the exact same error message, the exact same problem, and the exact same solution.  It's an exact duplicate.  Did you read the answer?  How did applying that answer to your problem fail to solve your problem?

Comment: @Servy: I did read it, it is the same problem but the error message wording is different.

"Cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'" is not equal to "Argument type 'void' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Action'" Which is why I did not find it.

Comment: @TheColonel26 That's odd, because I *literally copy pasted the title of your question into google* and that was the top result.  That's how I found *the exact duplicate that covers your exact situation*.  The fact that you worded your question slightly different both *didn't inhibit your ability to find the duplicate*, nor does it change the fact that it's the exact same problem with the exact same solution.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on code that previously compiled (cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'). The line of code showing the error is the EXACT same as the one that had been working. Anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your `Invoke` method is expecting an `Action` but you are trying to pass it the return value of a method which in this case is `void`. Instead you can use a lambda to create the `Action`:

```
Invoke(() => Method2(testParam));
```

Or to be more explicit:

```
Action a = () => Method2(testParam);
Invoke(a);
```

The reason the first version works for you is that passing a method without trailing `()` is shorthand for the code above. So these are equivalent:

```
Invoke(Method1);
Invoke(() => Method1());
```

Comment: Why does Invoke(Method1) work though? Why does the compiler assume I want send Invoke an Action instead of the return type of the method?

Comment: I'll add that in my answer.

Comment: @TheColonel26 Because in that case you are not calling the method because you don't have `()` after it.  You are passing the name of the method which C# interrupts as meaning you want to convert it to a delegate.

Answer (score 6):

Your code doesn't work because `Method2(testParam)` executes the method, instead of providing an action *that can be executed* any time in the future.

You need a lambda here:

```
Invoke(() => Method2(testParam));
```

The other code (`Invoke(Method1)`) works because you provide a delegate here to the method (note the missing parenthesis: no execution, just a reference to the method). A delegate can be converted to an action.

Comment: Me neither. Thanks @DavidG

Comment: side comment: the down voting is making stack impossible to participate in, lately.

my original comment:  wouldn't you need to make the same lamda for the previous call Invoke(Method1);.  Isn't Method 1 getting executed before body of Invoke is called?

Comment: @tatmanblue No, it is a delegate.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thnx.

Comment: @tatmanblue Regarding your first sentence, no it isn't. good quality content (aside from some examples like the DV on this) generally gets upvoted.